# Can't get SQL query results

Tags: 6, database

I used a PHP code to show results of this query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable
```

I want to get the number of rows in a specific table. This query works fine in phpMyAdmin, but it doesn't work when I place it in a template file.

I mean it doesn't return the number of rows.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Could you post the code how you tried to retrieve the result?

Comment: Please post the complete code not only the SQL. and are you using db_query() or mysql_query ?

Comment: Realyl Thanks, specially kantu. I used db_query and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template file should never contain code that executes a query; that should be done in a preprocess function, eventually.

The code to get the number of rows in a table is similar to the following one.

```
$count = db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {mytable}"));
```

The table name should always be put between curly brackets, which will be replaced with the prefix currently set for database tables.